# reusing laptop's windows 10 license

Tags: windows-10, laptop

i have an acer swift 3 laptop that comes with a pre installed windows 10 pro.
 i was trying to use the acer's recovery software to reset the laptop to it's factory settings but proved to be problematic. i was thinking of just reinstalling the OS through traditional method(bootable usb). i want to reuse the license that comes with the laptop. how do I do it? is there anyway to reuse the license key like just copying it from the laptop?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1138691/windows-license-with-thinkpad

Comment: You will be unable to reuse your OEM windows 10 license