# Can I recover a Windows key after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, oem, license-key

I'm wondering if, after installing Ubuntu, it would be possible to recover my OEM copy of Windows 11 if something goes wrong with Linux. I am considering installing Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish on my HP laptop, but want to know if Windows is recoverable if Linux has a problem (which has happened numerous times on my other machine.) I have not gone through the Windows setup process yet. Neither OS is actually installed, and I am currently running Ubuntu off of a live USB. I want to install Ubuntu, but want to make sure that Windows is recoverable if something goes wrong.

- Microsoft Windows 11 is preinstalled.
- I have not done the installation process yet. (Setting up a Microsoft account, Choosing a password, etc.)
- There is no hologram sticker on the device or packaging.
- I am running Ubuntu GNU/Linux off of a live USB as I write this.

Comment: Did your device come with Windows preinstalled? Does it have a Windows logo hologram sticker (typically on the bottom)?

Comment: @Daniel B No hologram sticker, but it's preinstalled. However, I haven't gone through the setup process yet.

Comment: Your now closed question at AU has enough comments and even an answer before being closed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411035/can-i-recover-a-windows-key-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: @ChanganAuto On Ask Ubuntu, I was told that I should ask on Super User. So, here I am!

Comment: Indeed but if you already got an answer I don't see the point of repeating the exact same thing here like you never learned anything new.

Comment: If the PC came with a Windows OEM installation, it _must_ have a Certificate of Authenticity (nowadays, that’s the Windows logo sticker). Check again.

Comment: @Daniel B There is no Windows sticker anywhere on the laptop or the packaging. Could it be on a website or something? There are QR codes all over it.

Comment: @Ramhound So even if I format the drive, use Ubuntu for a year, and boot from a Windows install medium, it will still detect the key?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I just wanted to confirm before accidentally erasing a $120 key. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ramhound Just for clarification: - Microsoft Windows 11 is preinstalled. - I have not done the installation process yet. - There is no hologram sticker on the device or packaging. - I am running Ubuntu GNU/Linux off of a live USB as I write this. Does that help?

Comment: @Ramhound By "installation process," I mean setting up a Microsoft account, choosing a password, etc.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, I edited the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows License with Thinkpad](https://superuser.com/questions/1138691/windows-license-with-thinkpad)

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering if, after installing Ubuntu, it would be possible to recover my OEM copy of Windows 11 if something goes wrong with Linux.

Windows 11 automatically detects any OEM licenses Store in the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) table of your device.

It’s completely unnecessary to recover the key all supported versions of Windows automatically detect the key when being installed. Windows 10+ also automatically activate using a digital entitlement system.

> I am considering installing Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish on my HP laptop, but want to know if Windows is recoverable if Linux has a problem (which has happened numerous times on my other machine.)

You would need to install the same edition that came with your device but you will absolutely have zero issues reinstalling Windows 11.

> There is no hologram sticker on the device or packaging.

If there isn’t a COA sticker, then it’s impossible for it to actually have an OEM Windows installation, Microsoft doesn’t allow OEM manufactures to install Windows without their COA sticker.

Retail Windows licenses are NOT stored in the ACPI table, if the device hasn’t been logged into, then you would need to provide the license key when you reinstalled Windows 11. I am going to guess the sticker does indeed exist, if it was manufactured by one of the major OEMs that exist today, given that Windows 11 retail licenses were not available until this month.

Retail licenses come with a piece of cardboard that has the COA sticker on it. Just to be clear, you don’t have a retail license to Windows 11, the COA sticker exists somewhere on your device likely underneath the battery.

Comment: What is an ACPI table?

Comment: The ACPI table stores specific programmable information about the device by the manufacture of the device.  One of those entries is the Windows key for your device.

Comment: Is the ACPI table stored on the SSD or in the BIOS or what?

Comment: @UxuginLinux More-or-less The "BIOS", ie on the motherboard.

Comment: @UxuginLinux - It’s neither stored in the BIOS nor the SSD. UEFI can simply access the ACPI table.  It’s separate, part of the motherboard, but it’s definitely not stored in the UEFI (modern machines don’t have a BIOS)